# configure database schema in spring boot application using jdbc template

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a spring boot application using spring jdbc template for DAO layer connecting to Oracle DB. The DB username is different than the schema on which the queries will be run. Hence when the queries are run it needs to run using a different schema and I do not want to prefix the hardcoded value for the schema(For ex `select * from user1.table.....`)

I researched a bit and couldn't find a simple and straight way to do that.

For ex if I were using JPA I could have simply configured the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=<schema name>` but couldn't find an equivalent way of configuring the same when using spring jdbc

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and didn't find an ideal way to do it. I ended up setting the schema in SQL when the app loaded. At least I was able to reuse `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema`, which I already had set for the JPA default schema.

```
final String schemaName = jpaProperties.getProperties().get("hibernate.default_schema");
jdbcTemplate.execute("SET SCHEMA '" + schemaName + "'");
```

This clearly isn't ideal, but it is better than defining your schema in multiple places.

(Note: I autowired both the JpaProperties and JdbcTemplate.)

Answer (score -3):

You need to use the Oracle JDBC Driver.

A good example can be found in [this mykong article](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-oracle-example/):

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the answer I'm looking for. In the above properties there is no property for schema.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29474575)

Comment: @Reborn: This is very clearly more than just a link.